# Combining multiple select queries with different where clauses

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL Server. I need to combine these select queries. Ideally, I could wrap the query in a Select Into statement and store the results in a new table. I've tried a few different approaches to solve this but I've been unsuccessful so far.

```
Select Distinct MatchId, TeamId, JerseyNumber,
        SUM(DistanceMeters) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchId, TeamId, JerseyNumber) AS PlayerTotalDistanceMeters,
        SUM(DistanceMeters) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchId, TeamId) AS TeamTotalDistanceMeters
From Distance
Order By MatchId, TeamId, JerseyNumber


Select Distinct d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber,
        AVG(d.PlayerField_x) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS FirstHalfPlayerAvg_x,
        AVG(d.PlayerField_y) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS FirstHalfPlayerAvg_y
From Distance AS d
Inner Join MatchPeriods AS m
On d.MatchId = m.MatchId
Where d.FrameNumber between m.FirstHalfStartFrame and m.FirstHalfEndFrame


Select Distinct d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber,
        AVG(d.PlayerField_x) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS SecondHalfPlayerAvg_x,
        AVG(d.PlayerField_y) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS SecondHalfPlayerAvg_y
From Distance AS d
Inner Join MatchPeriods AS m
On d.MatchId = m.MatchId
Where d.FrameNumber between m.SecondHalfStartFrame and m.SecondHalfEndFrame
```

Comment: Do you want to combine the results of all the queries or queries itself to make a single query?

Comment: Union all? The CTE? What did you try? Examples, please

Answer (score 0):

You can join all three into 1 using `UNION` And then contain a new column specifying category

```
with table_1 as (Select Distinct MatchId, TeamId, JerseyNumber,
            SUM(DistanceMeters) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchId, TeamId, JerseyNumber) AS PlayerTotalDistanceMeters,
            SUM(DistanceMeters) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchId, TeamId) AS TeamTotalDistanceMeters,
    
    'TOTAL_SUM' AS CATEGORY
    
    
    From Distance
),

table_2 as (
    
    Select Distinct d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber,
            AVG(d.PlayerField_x) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS FirstHalfPlayerAvg_x,
            AVG(d.PlayerField_y) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS FirstHalfPlayerAvg_y,

'FIRST_HALF_AVG' AS CATEGORY
    
    From Distance AS d
    Inner Join MatchPeriods AS m
    On d.MatchId = m.MatchId
    Where d.FrameNumber between m.FirstHalfStartFrame and m.FirstHalfEndFrame
),

table_3 as (
    
    Select Distinct d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber,
            AVG(d.PlayerField_x) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS SecondHalfPlayerAvg_x,
            AVG(d.PlayerField_y) OVER (PARTITION BY d.MatchId, d.TeamId, d.JerseyNumber) AS SecondHalfPlayerAvg_y,
    
    'SECOND_HALF_AVG' AS CATEGORY
    
    From Distance AS d
    Inner Join MatchPeriods AS m
    On d.MatchId = m.MatchId
    Where d.FrameNumber between m.SecondHalfStartFrame and m.SecondHalfEndFrame
),

combined_table as (


select * from table_1
union
select * from table_2
union
select * from table_3

)

select * from combined_table
```